# Why does csrf verification fail after validation error in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, csrf, django-csrf

I have a Django site that has an admin site associated with it.  One of the models that is registered with the admin is called `Article`, and it has a field called `content` that is required.  If the user leaves this field blank, it will show them a **validation error** saying that the field is required.

However, if they get this validation error and then click the save button again, they will be given a **csrf_verification failed error**.  I have checked, and the csrf token is being passed, and a different csrf token is passed when the user makes the request that generates the validation error from when the user makes the request that generates the csrf_token error.

Any ideas why the csrf_token error is happening?  Is this normal Django behavior, or is it specific to my site?  What are the next steps I should take to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is it happening every time.

Comment: Yes, I can replicate it 100% of the time.  I cause a validation error, make the correction, try saving again, and the csrf error pops up.

Comment: I fixed the problem, although I do not yet know specifically what it was.  I had a method in the Article model which generated a string that contained the Article's page in an iframe for a preview of it that could be displayed in the admin.  When the article was not yet created, the iframe showed a 404 page.  For some reason, when I set this method to return a blank string when the article was not yet created (if not self.pk), it fixed this error, though I do not know why